# A 'conjecture' on critical elliptic pde

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I conjecture the following.

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^3-\overline{B_1(0)}$. Define
$$E_{\Omega}(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2dx-\frac{1}{6}\int_{\Omega}|u|^6dx.$$
$E_{\mathbb{R}^3}$ is defined similarly:
$$E_{\mathbb{R}^3}(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\\mathbb{R}^3}|\nabla u|^2dx-\frac{1}{6}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|u|^6dx.$$

Consider the exterior problem
$$
\Delta u+|u|^4u=0,~~
,~~~u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$$

It's well-known that if $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^3$, then the problem has a unique radial positive solution given by 
$$W(x)=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{|x|^2}{3})^{1/2}}.$$

Conjecture: If $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^3-B_1(0)$, then the problem admits a unique nontrivial nonnegative radial solution $u$. Moreover, 
$E_{\Omega}(u)=E_{\mathbb{R}^3}(W)$.

I appreciate very much if anynone can prove this or can tell me the existed source of answer or give counterexamples.

Comment: You want $u$ to be zero (and not equal to, say, $1$) along the unit sphere? 

Comment: Yes, I want zero boundary condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking a Kelvin transform of the PDE.  It will send it to a new PDE on $|x| \le 1$.  IN this case, since hte PDE is critical, you should get the same PDE.    Some care will need to be taken at the origin.  If you are looking for a "fast decay" solution of the exterior problem, ie.  one for which $ |x| |u(x)| $ is bounded  then the Kelvin transform will be a classical solution on the unit ball and yet I think this is impossible.   So I think the only fast decay solution is $u=0$.

Comment: Craig, thanks for telling me this technique. 

I also realized that the answer should be straight forward from the known result.

Assume $u$ is a solution to the problem (with certain regularity, for example, $C^1$), then extend $u$ by zero to the whole space, then we must have $u=0$ by the characterization of solutions to the cauchy problem $\Delta u+u^5=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 

Comment: I don't think that works.   Assume $u$ is positive solution on exteror of ball.  By Hopft you will have non zero gradient on |x|=1.  Let $v$ denote extension to full space (zero inside ball).   CHeck carefully that $-\Delta v$ has  a non zero surface measure supported on $|x|=1$.  So $ v$ satisfies something along the liens of $ -\Delta v = v^5  + \sigma $ in R^N  where sigma the surface measure.  

